# Spaces get trimmed when I use org table in (R) code block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, org-table

Please, help! I use literate programming and I want to use org-mode tables as data for my R code blocks. However, **when it comes to cell values that have meaningful leading and trading spaces org-mode either removes it or escapes the quotes**. I would very like to leave such spaces in place when I quote the value in the org table cell.

Example:

```
#+name: test-table
| name      | string                                                            |
|-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------|
| example-1 | "  a string with very important leading and trailing spaces "     |
| example-2 | ""  a string with very important leading and trailing spaces ""   |
| example-3 | """  a string with very important leading and trailing spaces """ |
| example-4 | \"  a string with very important leading and trailing spaces \"   |
| example-5 | '  a string with very important leading and trailing spaces '     |
| example-6 | \'  a string with very important leading and trailing spaces \'   |
```

```r
#+header: :var data = test-table
#+begin_src R  :tangle no :results verbatim
  ## get value column and quote it to see if spaces are in place
  paste0("\"", data[[2]], "\"")
#+end_src
```

It gives me the following results:

```
#+RESULTS:
: "a string with very important leading and trading spaces"
: ""
: ""
: "\"  a string with very important leading and trading spaces \""
: "'  a string with very important leading and trading spaces '"
: "\'  a string with very important leading and trading spaces \'"
```

What I would like to have is just a string as it was in the table. Like this:

```
: "  a string with very important leading and trading spaces "
```

I looked where it gets trimmed and I think it is somewhere in `orgtbl-to-generic` function, but it converts the table (in lisp format) back to org table and uses custom export backend to print it to tsv. I could not figure out where it removes the spaces and how to fix it. It might be a bug. I think that normal behavior should be the one that I was expected initially.

Can you, please, help me with getting around it?